# If I drag an image from one Photoshop window to another open window will I lose image quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, canvas

If I drag an image from one Photoshop window to another open window (both same size canvas and at 72 dpi) will I lose image quality? I know it won't if it's a smart object, but what if it's not?

If the image is say 1500px by 1500px and my canvases are both 1000px by 1000px
can I drag from one window to another and then scale up a bit without losing image quality? (Since my original image is large and was scaled down in the first place when put in the original psd. file.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you don't have a Photoshop preference set to resize the image, your duplicate will simply get adjusted automatically to the resolution of the canvas you copy it into.

It will simply appear bigger in the smaller canvas.

If you then need to resize that image then yes it will "lose quality" in the sense that it will become smaller than your original image!

The original image in the original file will not be affected at all; it's like doing a copy/paste, and **the files are technically not linked together**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no if the original image was pretty sharp to begin with. Then that is half the battle create a layer, do it in small adjustments, using sliders to adjust where you see it needs it ie; blurriness, color, shadows etc. Make a copy from this and you should be good.